# .htaccess rewrite with short url (redirector)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i've a question about

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

my idea:

```
http://redir.com/? to execute redir.php
http://redir.com or http://redir.com/ to execute index.php
```

how to make the htaccess?

tnx

Comment: Do you wish to include the `#blah` url hash? It isn't possible, as that is not sent from the client to the server.  Or do you just want to redirect anything with a query string `?...` to redir.php and root requests to index.php? Please clarify.

Comment: yes, te hash is necesary, my redirection is in javascript-php hash based, i need to separe the redir part from de index with ? char.

Comment: I'm still confused about what you want to do. `http://redir.com/?#blah to execute redir.php` **?** `http://redir.com or http://redir.com/ to execute index.php` **index.php is already executed automatically when you visit http://redir.com or http://redir.com/**. From your rewrite rules it looks like you're trying to execute a php file when visting the same URL but without the extension. For example `http://redir.com/test` to execute `http://redir.com/test.php`

Comment: ok, my simplified question is...

how i can to make the htaccess to execute redir.php with http://redir.com/?#blah and don't to affect the index site.

Comment: @kjetilh http://redir.com/test to http://redir.com/test.php is the same idea, but i need http://redir.com / ? to execute http://redir.com/test.php is possible?

Comment: Yes, but you can't create a rewrite based on the hash sign as its not transmitted to the server as @MichaelBerkowski said.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the purpose of hash it's only figurative to specify the data after... but not necessary in this case. I edited the question...

Answer (score 0):

The following rewrite rules will rewrite http://redir.com?blah to http://redir.com/test.php.

That means http://redir.com/test.php will be executed instead of the normal http://redir.com/index.php when visiting http://redir.com but **only** if the query string `?blah` is set.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blah$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ test.php [L,NC,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: http://redir.com / ?blah =>execute=> test.php and
 http://redir.com / =>execute=> index.php (Don't affected) ????????????????